# Starting with Chrome 67, debugger no longer fire iframes network events in my extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension no longer works properly after upgrating to Chrome 67, since the attached debugger doesn't fire iframes network events anymore

Does anyone have the same issue? Thanks

Comment: This can be caused by OOPIF (out-of-process iframes) enabled in Chrome 67 by default. I think you'll have to explicitly attach your debuggers to the frame targets you want to debug.

Comment: You're right! Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried to explicitly attach the debugger to the frames, but, since there're multiple iframes in the page, it just throws the error "Another debugger is already attached to the tab"

Comment: I'm not familiar with chrome.debugger API but, judging by the documentation, since `tabId` is optional you can try attaching to target `id` without specifying tabId. In the demo extension chrome.debugger.getTargets lists iframes as separate targets.

Comment: I'll try. Thanks